# Is there any software on Ubuntu to use a computer like a smart display?

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar

I'm looking for a program that can run in the background showing multiple calendars, image gallery, news feed etc.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't know if such software exists, but I think that this can be the most handy solution: https://magicmirror.builders

Comment: @Helio That looks like a promising answer to OP's question. However is it only for raspberry pi?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: yes, it's originally intended for Raspberry Pi, but installing It on Ubuntu seems to be relatively easy: https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror#manual-installation

Comment: @Helio I think this question should be reopened and your answer posted...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if such software exists, but I think that this can be the most handy solution: [magicmirror.builders](https://magicmirror.builders)

It's originally intended for Raspberry Pi, but installing It on Ubuntu seems to be relatively easy (see https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror#manual-installation).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I didn't know how to ask the question which makes this thread difficult. The Magic Mirror site is exactly what I wanted.
Thanks